# How to split/filter events from perf.data?

Tags: perf

**Question**: Is there are a way to extract the samples for a specific event from a perf.data that has multiple events?

**Context**

I have a recorded sample of two events which I took by running something like

```
perf record -e cycles,instructions sleep 30
```

As far as I can see, other perf commands such as `perf diff` and `perf script` don't have an events filter flag. So it would be useful to split my **perf.data** into **cycles.perf.data** and **instructions.perf.data**.

Thanks!